# How to interchange multi dimension array keys

Tags: php

i have an array format like (mysql result array)

```
$new_array=Array ( [0] => Array ( [quantity] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [quantity] => 25 ) [2] => Array ( [quantity] => 20 ) )
```

I have to convert this array into the following format

```
$new_array['quantity'][0]=5
$new_array['quantity'][1]=25
$new_array['quantity'][2]=20
```

How to convert this array format using any standard array method.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function in PHP that will accomplish this.

You can write a loop to iterate over the original array and generate the new format, though:

```
foreach($old_array as $i => $fields) {
    foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
        $new_array[$field][$i] = $value;
    }
}
```